# Останавливается основной поток пока не отработает await

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

При запуске `await ChangeDirectory(path)` основной поток останавливается и UI не откликается пока метод не отработает.

Вопрос 1: почему так происходит?

Вопрос 2: как сделать чтобы  UI обновлялся при каждом новом добавлении в ObservableCollection ?

```
public ObservableCollection<FoldersVm> Folders { get; }

public async void MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var listBox = sender as ListBox;
    var foldersVm = listBox?.SelectedItem as FolderVm;
    if (foldersVm != null)
    {
        var path = foldersVm.FullPath;
        if (File.GetAttributes(path) == FileAttributes.Directory)
        {
            await ChangeDirectory(path);
            _previousPath = path;
        }
    }
}

private Task ChangeDirectory(string path)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate()
        {
            Folders.Clear();
            foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path))
            {
                var attr = File.GetAttributes(dir);
                if ((attr & FileAttributes.Hidden) != 0 || (attr & FileAttributes.System) != 0)
                    continue;
                Folders.Add(new FolderVm(Path.GetFileName(dir), ImagesHelper.GetFolderImage(dir), dir));
            }
            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(file) == ".jpg")
                    Folders.Add(new FolderVm(Path.GetFileName(file), ImagesHelper.GetFrozenImage(file, 200), file));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**ImageHelper.GetFolderImage**

```
public static ImageSource GetFolderImage(string path)
    {
        var sf = ShellObject.FromParsingName(path) as ShellFolder;
        if (sf.Thumbnail != null)
            return sf.Thumbnail.BitmapSource.Clone() as ImageSource;
        return null;
    }
```

**Update for VladD**

Проблема была в методе GetFolderImage, решил ее так:

```
public static ImageSource GetFolderImage(string path)
    {
        var sf = ShellObject.FromParsingName(path) as ShellFolder;
        if (sf.Thumbnail != null)
        {
            var a = sf.Thumbnail.BitmapSource;
            a.Freeze();
            return a;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Я помню этот код! Где вы все его берете-то?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, вы что-то путаете, весь этот код я написал сам!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что в коде

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate() {
```

<s>вторая</s> третья строка отменяет первую. Первая строка запускает лямбду в фоновом потоке. <s>Вторая</s> Третья строка из лямбды (асинхронно) запускает делегат в UI-потоке, и блокирует его на время выполнения всего делегата.

Можно попробовать асинхронизировать функцию `ChangeDirectory`. Вам понадобится модельный DTO-объект для переброски данных, т. к. VM-объекты обладают thread affinity (то есть, должны создаваться в главном потоке).

```
class FolderEntryModel // это ваш DTO-объект
{
    public string FileName, Image, DirectoryName;
}

static void EnumerateDirectoriesWithProgress(
        string path,
        IProgress<FolderEntryModel> progress,
        CancellationToken ct)
{
    foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path))
    {
        var attr = File.GetAttributes(dir);
        if ((attr & FileAttributes.Hidden) != 0 || (attr & FileAttributes.System) != 0)
            continue;
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            break;
        progress.Report(new FolderEntryModel()
                        {
                            FileName = Path.GetFileName(dir),
                            Image = ImagesHelper.GetFolderImage(dir),
                            DirectoryName = dir
                        });
    }
}

async Task ChangeDirectory(string path, CancellationToken ct)
{
    Folders.Clear();
    var progress = new Progress<FolderEntryModel>(m =>
        {
            if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                Folders.Add(new FolderVM(m.FileName, m.Image, m.DirectoryName));
        });
    await Task.Run(() => EnumerateDirectoriesWithProgress(path, progress, ct));
}
```

Нам ещё нужно добавить токен для отмены как поле:

```
CancellationTokenSource CurrentDirectoryReadCancellation;
```

Теперь для того, чтобы запустить новое сканирование, и отменить старое, делаем так:

```
async Task CancelDirectoryChangeAndStartNew(string path)
{
    CurrentDirectoryReadCancellation?.Cancel();
    var cts = CurrentDirectoryReadCancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    await ChangeDirectory(RootFolder, cts.Token);
    // если никто не начался после нас, подчистим
    if (CurrentDirectoryReadCancellation == cts)
        CurrentDirectoryReadCancellation = null;
}
```

`Progress<T>` позволяет перебрасывать событие в UI-поток, таким образом имеем лёгкий вариант producer/consumer'а.

---

Обновление: добавил в код возможность отмены.

Comment: если придираться, то на второй строке - скобочка :)

Comment: @Grundy: Исправил :)

Comment: гут :-)) принято :-D

Comment: @VladD, в строчке `progress.Report` вылетает исключение `Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.`

Comment: @Lightness: Тогда вы делаете что-то не так, как у меня в коде. Опишите, чем ваш код отличается от моего.

Comment: @VladD, проблема была не в вашем коде. Спасибо за хороший ответ!

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @Lightness: `Freeze` — правильное решение, да. Иначе приходилось бы и это выгружать в UI-поток.

Comment: @VladD, не могли бы вы дополнить вопрос тем, как можно отменить await в  случае если запустился еще один точно такой же поток? То есть если такой же поток запускается, то первый должен полностью остановиться. Я так понимаю нужно использовать `CancellationToken` ?

Comment: @Lightness: Сейчас сделаем :)

Comment: @Lightness: Готово.

Comment: Разобрался и все понял. Спасибо :)

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста!